# check userid existance on nested array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a dataset like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da028f8926a6200f408e531"),
    "content" : [ 
        "hello world"
    ],
    "set" : [ 
        {
            "setA" : [
              {
                "userid" : "5c35f1045643180d9488112f",
              },
              {
                "userid" : "5c35f1045643180d9488112g",
              }
            ],
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-14T07:07:44.036Z"),
            "id" : ObjectId("5da41ec053fce70ab03b9c18")
        }, 
        {
            "setA" : [
              {
                "userid" : "5c35f1045643180d9488112g",
              }
            ],
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-14T07:07:37.470Z"),
            "id" : ObjectId("5da41eb953fce70ab03b9c16")
        }, 
        {
            "setA" : [],
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-14T07:07:29.454Z"),
            "id" : ObjectId("5da41eb153fce70ab03b9c14")
        }
    ],
    "secondset": [
      {
        "userid" : "5c35f1045643180d9488112f",
      },
    ]
    "__v" : 0,
}
```

Now I want to search the userid exist on `setA` array or not
I am bit confused how to write the query.
If this case is on `secondset` array then I know how to check. Like this query:

```
db.CollectionName.findOne(
  { _id: ObjectId("5da028f8926a6200f408e531") },
  { secondset: { $elemMatch: { userid: req.body.userid } }
)
```

by this query if userid exist then return the userid otherwise return []. 
So I can further proceed with a condition like

```
if (data.length > 0) {
  //Already exist
} else {
  //Not exist
  //Do some stuff here
}
```

But I don't get the response on a nested array. I wrote the Query but not getting success. Query was:

```
db.CollectionName.findOne(
  { _id: ObjectId("5da028f8926a6200f408e531"), "set.id": ObjectId("5da41eb953fce70ab03b9c16") },
  { "set.$.setA": { $elemMatch: { userid: "5c35f1045643180d9488112f" } }
)
```

with this Query I am getting the error i.e `Cannot use $elemMatch projection on a nested field.`

Is there anyone who can guide me on how to solve this. Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: I think you can just specify the query's filter criteria as `{ "set.setA.userid": "5c...g" }` or `{ "set.setA.userid": { $in: [ "5c...g", "xyz" ] } }`. And use it with `find` or `findOne` methods. There is no need to use `$elemMatch` operator (this is used to specify multiple criteria for the same field). Also, see [MongoDB manual - Query Arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#query-arrays). and [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

Answer (score 0):

We need to use nested `$elemMatch`.

**The following query can get us the expected output:**

```
db.collection.find({
  "set":{
    $elemMatch:{
      "setA":{
        $elemMatch:{
          "userid" : "5c35f1045643180d9488112f"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```